# Wordpress search result to match exact word

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get the Wordpress search results to match the exact search key to a word in post.

I have tried the solution from the link below but the search results still returns posts with titles that has words that matches part of the search key:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177183/make-a-wp-query-search-match-exactly-the-search-term/17786

For example, the search key is `thank`, I would like the result to be something like `Thank you so much` and not include `Thanking is important`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this bellow code.
That code search your word inside post content only. after use that code the search oparation dose not perform on post title.

```
//searh contenet only
function _search_by_content_only( $search, $wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if(empty($search)) {
        return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query
    }
    $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
    $search =
    $searchand = '';
    foreach ((array)$q['search_terms'] as $term) {
        $term = esc_sql($wpdb->esc_like($term));
        $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_content regexp '[[:<:]]".$term."[[:>:]]')";
        $searchand = ' AND ';
    }
    if (!empty($search)) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
        if (!is_user_logged_in())
            $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
    }
    return $search;
}
add_filter('posts_search', '_search_by_content_only', 500, 2);
```

Try the above code and let me know the result.